# Call to a member function getId() on null in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, request

I'm trying to retrieve the values ​​of an attribute passed in request, I have tried, I can not, and it returns a NULL, when I make a var_dump on the attribute.

First of all I created a form to enter a comment, and when we click on validate, this page will have to take you back to a page where I have the comment list for each doctor, but I only receive this error which tells me "Call to a member function getId () on null" because I can not recover the value of doctor

**Controller of create comments**

```
public function commentCreateAction(Request $request, Booking $bookings)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    //  $medecin = $booking->getMedecin();
    $patient = $bookings->getPatient();

    $repoMedecin = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin');

    $medecin = $repoMedecin->findOneBy(array(
        'id' => $request->query->get("medecin")
    ));

    $bookings = $em->getRepository("DoctixFrontBundle:Booking")->findBy(array(
        "patient" => $patient
    ));

    $comments = new Comment();
    $comments->setMedecin($medecin);
    $comments->setPatient($patient);

    $form = $this->createForm('Doctix\PatientBundle\Form\CommentType', $comments);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($comments);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:comments.html.twig', array(
            'id' => $comments->getMedecin()->getId(),
            'comments' => $comments, 
            'bookings' => $bookings
        ));

    }

    return $this->render('DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:create.html.twig', array(
        'comment' => $comment,
        'form'    => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**Controller from the list of comments**

```
public function commentsAction(Request $request){

    $em  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repoMedecin = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin');

    $medecin = $repoMedecin->findOneBy(array(
        'id' => $request->query->get("medecin")
    )); 

    $patient = $em->getRepository("DoctixPatientBundle:Patient")->findOneBy(array(
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
    ));

    $bookings = $em->getRepository("DoctixFrontBundle:Booking")->findBy(array(
        "patient" => $patient
    ));


    ***
    $comments = $em->getRepository("DoctixPatientBundle:Comment")
        ->getCommentsForDoc($medecin->getId());
    ***

    return $this->render('DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:comments.html.twig', array(
        'comments' => $comments,
        'bookings' => $bookings
    ));
}
```

My mistake is in this controller.

to have the comments of a doctor, I have a function in my repository

**Repository**

```
public function getCommentsForDoc($docId, $approved = true)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.medecin = :medecin_id')
        ->addOrderBy('c.created')
        ->setParameter('medecin_id', $docId);

    if (false === is_null($approved))
        $qb->andWhere('c.approved = :approved')->setParameter('approved', $approved);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**Routing of commentsAction and createcomment**

```
patient_comments:
    path:  /patient/medecin/comments
    defaults: { _controller: DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:comments}

patient_comments_create:
    path:  /patient/medecin/{id}/create
    defaults: { _controller: DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:commentCreate}
```

**View of commentsAction**

```
{% for booking in bookings %}

    <div class="list_general" id="liste">
    <a href="#0" class="wish_bt"></a>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <figure>
        <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(booking.medecin.media, 'imageFile') }}"
            alt="{{ booking.medecin.media.imagename }}">
    </figure>

    <h4>
        Dr. {{ booking.medecin.user.prenom|capitalize }} {{ booking.medecin.user.nom|upper }} 
        <i class="pending">Pending</i>
    </h4>

    <a href="{{ path('patient_comments_create', {'id': booking.id}) }}?medecin={{ booking.medecin.id }}">
        Ajouter un Commentaire
    </a>

    <header>
        {% for comment in comments %}

        {% if comment is defined %}

        <label>Nom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly
            value=" {{ comment.patient.user.nom }} ">

        <label>Nom</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly
            value=" {{ comment.patient.user.prenom }} ">

        <p> a commenté </p> 
        <p>
            <time datetime="{{ comment.created|date('c') }}"> 
                {{ comment.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}
            </time> 
        </p>
    </header>

    <label>My Comments</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly
        value=" {{ comment.comment }} ">
    {% else %}
        <p> Il n'y a pas encore de commentaires à propos de ce médecin. Soyez le premier à commenter....</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% endfor %} 

{% endfor %}
```

**my layout where there is the Feedback tab and where I call my route**

```
   <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Mon profil">
                    <a class="nav-link link-white" href="{{ path('patient_comments')}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i>
                        <span class="nav-link-text">FeedBack</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to get the medicin id from the request->server - have you stored the id somehow there? Maybe you could include the information how your routing is defined for the commentsAction (or if you invoke this action in some other way)? In normal case you would have the medicin id included in your route definition - and it would be passed as normal function parameter to your commentsAction.

Comment: @ejuhjav, 
sorry for the $ request-> server, it was a try I was doing,
I'm going to update it, it was $ request-> query-> get

Comment: Can you update your question, and show the whole process of the `commentsAction`, I mean the route info, the action in controller and the view where you are using this action, or anywhere you are using the `commentsAction`? it is important to show what data you are sending to controllers, to understand what is happening.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez, I've updating my post.

Comment: @MohamedSacko in this line `$medecin = $repoMedecin->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->query->get("medecin")));` you are getting the medecin id that I suppose you are passing in another place using GET variables in the URL, Are you sure you are passing the data correctly? Can you make a `var_export / var_dump` of this value to ensure the reception of data???

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez, the var_dump of this value return me NULL, I've do it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question is still lacking the information how exactly you are accessing this route - i.e. why you have made the assumption that the medicin id would be passed in the request params - to me it just looks like your route definition is missing the id:

```
patient_comments:
    path:  /patient/medecin/{id}/comments
    defaults: { _controller: DoctixPatientBundle:Patient:comments}
```

and

```
public function commentsAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repoMedecin = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin');

    $medecin = $repoMedecin->find($id);
    ...
```

Comment: I access this route through a layout that defines my different tabs.and it's in the Feedback tab that I have the route patient_comments

Comment: i've updating my post in adding the layout where i call the route patient_comments. Thanks

Comment: so, there are two options that I can see. 1) as assumed in this answer based on your controller code (where you try to access specific medicin id), you just need to pass that medicin id from your template to that route path('patient_comments', {id: medicin_id}) - or 2) you are actually trying to get/display something else where you don't need that medicin id at all.